# carry word to new line every 15 characters

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular8

I use angular material and I need to transfer words to a new line, if it is more than 15 words, I need a function for this. That's what I tried, but it does not suit me

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="Name">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Name  </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" style="width:10em;word-wrap: break-word;"> {{element.Name}} </td>
        </ng-container>
```

Comment: You need to write code to break the name apart into separate strings if the requirement is every 15 words

Answer (score 0):

You can take a CSS only approach, the words will move to a new line if the character limit hits 15; this is done via `word-wrap` and max-width of [99]ch;

relevant **HTML**:

```
  <!-- Name Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> <div class='breakWord'>{{element.name}}</div> </td>
  </ng-container>
```

relevant **CSS**:

```
.breakWord{ word-wrap: break-word; max-width: 15ch;}
```

complete [working stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rb3l1y)